# Trigger event in HTML <select> box when the same entry is selected again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

In a HTML form, I use a drop-down list like this:

```
<select onchange="send()">
  <option value="a">Option A</option>
  <option value="b">Option B</option>
  <option value="c">Option C</option>
</select>
```

When the user changes the selected entry, `send()` is called, which basically uses `jQuery.ajax(...)` to send the new value to the server. This works fine.

When the transmission fails for some reason, the user is informed about the error. Most users will then select the same entry again to retry. Now the problem is that this will not trigger the `onchange` event again because the value hasn't changed. What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Use `onclick` instead of `onchange`

Comment: Or reset the selection when the the AJAX fails: `selectNode.selectedIndex = null`

Comment: Did you tried to use `onclick`? Every click on select will trigger `send()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
HTML

```
<select id="chg">
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$("select#chg").mouseup(function() {
    var open = $(this).data("isopen");

    if(open) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }

    $(this).data("isopen", !open);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T4yUm/107/)

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach like this to remember the last selected option. In the case of an error, I revert to this state. Thus, when the user retries, the `onchange` event will fire again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a empty value option

```
<option value=''></option>
```

Which is by default selected as first load, When error occurs for any selection you can select 'empty' option from select box. So for next time user will need to selection option and your 'send()' function will call.

```
// Selection empty option by code
$('#selectBoxId').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use onclick event

Comment: Well, the problem I see with the `onclick` event is that it will not trigger when the keyboard is used to cycle through the entries firstplace. But maybe a combination of `onlick` and `onchange` will do.